# Find intersection of two semi-circles

Tags: circles

I know how to calculate the intersection points of two circles. But I wasn't able to adjust the formula in my Python program so it would also apply for semi-circles.

How can I find the intersection points of two semi-circles?

For example, with which formula can I calculate the intersection points of semi-cirle $a$ and semi-circle $b$? Notice that the intersection points on the red line should **not** be calculated. You can actually call it arc $a$ and arc $b$.

[image: semi-cirle example]

Answer (score 0):

Compute the intersection points of the full circles to find candidates. Then throw away the candidates that don’t lie on the semicircles.

Comment: Isn't there another way without calculating the full circle?

Comment: I think it’s unlikely that a simpler method exists.